# Are answers that provide complementary information welcomed?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30661/what-are-the-main-reasons-for-capping-interest-rates-in-spain/30665?noredirect=1#comment112365_30665) made me wonder if Politics.SE encourages answers that do not directly address the question, but provide interesting complementary information that helps users better understand the context.

I saw this happening lots of times on SO ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819925/2780791)) and I think it is a good thing (thus I upvote them)

**Question:** Are answers that provide complementary information welcomed? (i.e. should be upvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally speaking, I've seen supplementary answers used and used them myself on nearly all SE sites I've been active on. They get upvoted and sometimes even get accepted.

There's nothing wrong with writing one, in my view, when the essence of what you'd like to write is already captured in an answer or two - except for a few extra points that would not fit in a comment.